# Change already uploaded image when editing item - React, Javascript, NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I have a feature on my website where calendar events can be created. Those events are stored in my database and they can have a name, description, date, time and **image**.

Adding events is a pure admin permission and up to this point we didn't have editing in place. I'm currently trying to add that feature.

I'm missing some way of thinking about this. **How can I signify that an image is already added for an event and allow a way to change the image?**

I was thinking of just downloading the image temporarily and adding it as a value to the input[type="file"], but from my research it seems that isn't possible.

For images I'm just storying a relative path to the image, which is being stored on a different server.